# In vim, how can I remap <tab> without also remapping <Ctrl+i>?

Tags: vim

I like to use tab to jump between split windows, so I have `map <tab> <C-W><C-W>` in my .vimrc. Yet I noticed that this makes it so that Ctrl+I doesn't behave as Ctrl+I anymore, but as Ctrl+W, Ctrl+W. How can I remap just `<tab>` but not `<C-i>`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.

Comment: had this keycode mapping/recognition problem been resolved in Vim 8, as of now (year 2017)? I find I can still reproduce Jon's example on my Vim 8.0

Comment: @llinfeng: No, unfortunately not. Bram is currently working on integrating a terminal into Vim; this seems to use a library produced by Paul Evans, so maybe this will eventually lead to an improvement on the handled keys, too. (But this is pure speculation at this time.)

Answer (score 4):

While remapping `<tab>` will always cause `<c-i>` to also be remapped, you can first remap `<c-i>` to something else with `nnoremap` to preserve its functionality. Since the pneumonic for `<c-o>` is "older", I use `<c-n>` for "newer":

```
" First remap <tab> (and <c-i>) to <c-n>
nnoremap <c-n> <tab>

" Now remap <tab> to something else
nnoremap <tab> <c-w><c-w>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all shortcuts are possible in Vim especially if it iss under a terminal. I do not recommend using a tab shortcut for that purpose. But an alternative solution might be the following:

```
" Note: Allows faster switching between windows with "Ctrl+w"! By Questor
nnoremap <silent> <C-w> <C-w><C-w>
inoremap <silent> <C-w> <Esc><C-w><C-w>
vnoremap <silent> <C-w> <Esc><C-w><C-w>
```

See an example of use in https://github.com/eduardolucioac/groovim/blob/master/.vimrc

[]'s

Answer (score 0):

If you're using iTerm you can just remap `<Ctrl+i>` to an arbitrary key combination and then map that to `<tab>` before remapping `<tab>` to something else.

This is what I have for navigating tabs with `<tab>` (after remapping `<Ctrl+i>` to `==` in iTerm):

```
nnoremap == <tab>
nnoremap <tab> :tabnext<CR>
```